# How to get the cursor point in a Window instead of whole desktop?

Tags: c++

How to get the cursor point in a Window instead of whole desktop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Win32 you use [ScreenToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952(v=vs.85).aspx) or [MapWindowPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert from system coordinates to window coordinates